# execute selection of dataframe based with if condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

When I print the following it selects the correct values: `df[(df['Pdem']>0)].`
However, I am not able to work this into an if condition (without the `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. - error) that sets the constraints at the right timeslots. I do not want any() or all() as i want the decision to be made per row of the dataframe.

I would like to set different constraints for Pb  in Gurobi per timeslot based on the size of Pdem per timeslot (T = total hours). I have tried various things such as loc (shown below), iterrows and regular boolean expressions.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Following did the trick

`model.addConstrs(((Pgen [t] - Pdem[t]) < 0) >> 0 <= P_grid_b[t] <= Pgridmax for t in range(T))
model.addConstrs((Pdem[t] == 0) >> 0 <= P_grid_b[t] <= 0 for t in range(T))`

Comment: I need some more clarification. If you want to pass the logical to an `if` conditional, it has to be a boolean (i.e. you have to use `any()`, `all()` etc.). If you want to make the decision per row, the best idea i can think of, is to iterate over the rows and set the constraint based on the condition of each row. However, I *FEEL* there is a vectorized way of doing this, perhaps you are searching for that way....

Comment: I feel that this is what i want: 'is to iterate over the rows and set the constraint based on the condition of each row'. The if just needs to check IF a certain value in a dataframe is of a certain size, before consecutive actions (the indented lines) are executed. How would you formulate that?

Comment: It appears that you already answered your own question. If you are trying to iterate over rows, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) link. If you think that is what you wanted to do, I would recommend **deleting this question**, to minimize the pollution in stackoveflow. If you still need a solution, ask here

Comment: It was just a workaround not a general solution i'm currently trying to set op the following without succes: (P_bat_disch is a decision variable and the eff(iciencies) are parameters. I would like the model to check the dec. var. per step and set the eff accordingly.
`if P_bat_disch [t]  >= 0:
    eff_disch = 0.1 #
    eff_ch = 0.1 #
elif P_bat_disch[t] >= 0.2:
    eff_disch = 0.3 #
    eff_ch = 0.3#
else:
    eff_disch = 0.8 #
    eff_ch = 0.8 #`

Comment: Thanks for following up. Would you mind updating your question with your findings, what you tried (including the code you removed) and a sample input dataframe and also an expected output dataframe/array. That way potential answerers have a good a starting point and you improve the chance of someone picking it up and providing some good answers. There is ambiguity in your question which can cause it to get downvoted.

Comment: Also, the logical condition you present here is illogical. Your second condition of `>= 0.2` will never get triggered. The first one will always be `True` if the second one is `True`, thus the second one will never activate, only the first and third (i.e. the `else`) block will be activated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the `apply` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1.0,1.0,(10,2)), columns= ["a", "b"])

def my_func_disch(x):
    if x >= 0 and x < 0.2:
        eff_disch = 0.1
    elif x >= 0.2:
        eff_disch = 0.3
    else:
        eff_disch = 0.8

    return eff_disch

df["eff_disch"] = df.a.apply(my_func_disch)
```